# How to display an image in React.js with Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Sorry if this is a duplicate question. I can't seem to solve this or find an answer.

Essentially I want to display an image so it responsively adjusts depending on screen size. I'm using the React-Bootstrap example and it just isn't working. Here is the code I'm using and here is a link to the example https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#media-content .

```
import React from 'react';
import {ResponsiveEmbed, Image} from 'react-bootstrap';



export default React.createClass ( {
    render() {
        return (
            <div style={{width: 660, height: 'auto'}}>
                <ResponsiveEmbed a16b9>
                    <embed type="image/href+xml" href = "https://static.pexels.com/photos/296886/pexels-photo-296886.jpeg"/>
                </ResponsiveEmbed>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

This is the App.jsx file it connects too

```
import React from "react"
import { render } from "react-dom"
import Footer from "./components/Footer"
import HeaderNavigation from "./components/HeaderNavigation"
import App1Container from "./containers/App1Container"
import Carousel from "./components/Carousel"
class App1 extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <HeaderNavigation />
          <Carousel />
          <App1Container/>
          <Footer/>
        </div>
    )
  }
}

render(<App1/>, document.getElementById('App1'))
```

Comment: It should be `a16by9` and not `a16b9`. See if that works.

Comment: The above worked. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be a16by9 and not a16b9. Answered by rishipuri

Answer (score 6):

If you want just image why not to use:

```
<Image src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/296886/pexels-photo-296886.jpeg" responsive />
```

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap Jumbotron stuff does not deal with background image. Try this instead 
at top of file:

```
import Jumbotron from "./src/img/1.png"
```

in your div:
     `<img style={{height:'auto',width:'100%'}} src={ Jumbotron }/>`

Comment: we can Use Image replace img ?

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing this code:

```
const responsiveEmbedInstance = (
<div style={{width: 500, height: 'auto'}}>
<ResponsiveEmbed a16by9>
  <embed type="image/svg+xml" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/296886/pexels-photo-296886.jpeg" />
</ResponsiveEmbed>
</div>
);
```

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/jayesh24/ywzw5hrt/

Comment: Hi Jayesh,

This is a component that links to the code below.

Answer (score 0):

Use react-bootstrap package

```js
import Image from "react-bootstrap/Image";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";

<Image src="image.png" fluid/>
```

Answer (score 0):

if stored in a data structure(const, var,...)

```
<img
  src={URL.createObjectURL(image)}
  alt="Error loading file"
/>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).